# WCF Service DllNotFoundException - project reference DLL has metadata file calling another DLL (by name) using DLL import...metadata file uneditable

Tags: .net, wcf, dll

Im trying to connect to a third party sdk with a number of dlls which I add to the project as references and they import okay. However, viewing their decompiled code,they call other dlls by name using dll import. These dlls cant be found by the system. Ive tried copying this dll in the project's bin folder, project's working directory...project's parent directory(D:/)...even windows system32 folder and syswow64...the dlls have both x64 and x86 bit versions which im sure i place in the correct directories because when i interchange the project's target platform, the error changes to a badimageexception...when I put the correct arch dll, I get a dllnotfoundexception...followed some advice I found about giving read and execute permissions to authenticated users in my directory but still no luck.Oh, and these dlls being called cant be added as project references...i get a com error. Dependency Walker hangs majorly when I try to analyse these dlls...the imported one and the oneit calls. A sample application using the same exact files runs smoothly on my machine...which is weirder. Im running Win 10 x64. The sample app targets x86 arch. My project has both configs but all generate the same dllnofoundexception . Console app with the same code also gets the same error.Please help

Comment: Are the dlls registered?  I did some reading and most sites indicate either compatibility mode is not working or dlls not registered.

Comment: regsvr32 fails to register both dlls...theyre 3rd party dlls so i dont think they need to be registered really..but i tried that too

Comment: Than there must be a compatibility issue.  This sounds similar to (probably not same KB) https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/kb4592438-bad-image-error-on-my-dll-after-windows/8c3c0412-df75-4ebc-a63f-b553a6bb2fbe  See following : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-older-apps-or-programs-compatible-with-windows-783d6dd7-b439-bdb0-0490-54eea0f45938